# IOS - UIScrollView borders and zoom

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, zooming, border

I'm implementing a gallery with a UIScrollView, and I've a problem if the picture haven't the same size as the  UIScrollView.
In this case, when the image is at normal size, there are borders as usual. But when I do zoom in the image, the borders makes bigger too.

I would like, if the image is zoomed and bigger than the UIScrollView, that the only visible part would be the image, not the borders.

And have no idea what to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: how you define your scrollview? can you give more information about your view and the scrollview? for example the width and heightm positioning and so on. i believe your UIScrollView is defined to small. you should make it full size and just fit your image in it.

Comment: Yes! It's true that, with images that are smaller than the UIScrollView there is no problem.
But the majority of the image that i'm going to show are bigger, and are scaled by the UIImageView to fit it.
What should I do to fix it so?

Answer (score 0):

You should have that image in `UIImageView` set in background and add one more view on top of that where you add all the icons and which should be zooming in scrollview. In this way that image will not be zooming and will look like the same in zooming and normal state also.